# When parent row link to child row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Example: I have category table with the FOREIGN KEY to the same table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
)
```

How to constraint the parent_id that it can't be the child parent_id.

Example: 
we have a parent's row where parent_id equal child's id:

```
['1', 'parent_name', '**2**']
```

Child row:

```
['2', 'child_name', '**1**']
```

How to fix this by MySQL?

Comment: You're basically trying to detect cycles in a directed graph. SQL is a very poor language for that. Consider another language, perhaps PHP itself.

Comment: I don't know how you could fix existing records without looking at them individually - moving forward you might be able to use a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already does not happen during insert (base on the defination of the table), you have foreign key on **parent_id** to **id** your example is a paradox, but it may happen during **update** of the table so you need to create a **trigger** for Update to prevent updating the table such as the example also For this case The `CHECK` constraint does not work, as I mentioned one way is to use a `trigger` for `before update`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_categories
BEFORE Update
   ON categories FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF EXISTS (select * from categories c where c.id=NEW.parent_id and c.parent_id=NEW.id) THEN
       set msg = "DIE: you can not make a parent of chield as it's chield...";
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
       // also you can make NEW as NULL for preventing update under mentioned condition
    END IF;    
END;
```